# What are the possible ways to keep Singleton classes in sync in any distributed platform?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I suppose singleton are per JVM only
but I am trying to keep them(state of singleton objects) in sync in distributed environment

And as we know Singleton have only one instance in JVM so when we get any changes in any JVM Singleton how we can update other JVM Singleton instances?

Here my focus is totally on keeping the state of objects in sync.

Comment: You need to learn inter-process communication in Java to perform interaction between JVM instances.

Comment: do you mean singletons of other classes or of the same class?

Comment: I mean I have a singleton class and I need to maintain the objects in sync in different jvms to be very specific(distributed environment)

Answer (score 0):

Have the singleton be a static field in the class

Comment: How will that help. Different VM different class loader... different Class instance. No use of making it static.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand the question... what exactly is being asked?

Comment: I guess object must be in sync means the instance state must be same across all JVMs.... for objects of same singleton class of course.

Comment: Can the instances be ever be same across JVMs? I suppose only the state can be maintained if possible. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly depends on what you want to be there just once (singleton). If it is data/state, you can check for a modern distributed database and how they keep the stat consistent across different instances (even eventually).

If you want a singular instance, you can use things that are unique in a computer network, like a SocketAddress (bound to a real hostname). Your "Distributed Singleton" starts up with trying to connect to that address(es) and if it proceeds it is just a delegate. If not, it can try to bind to that address - accepting connections from there, being the ONE - or just give up.

In delegate mode, all method calls to the instance are just sent via the socket to the ONE. 
Being the ONE it can track who is connected and map the incoming messages to method calls and reply according to its internal state.

This is quite a scribble without any failover, redundancy etc. but it should do the job in principle.

I'd suggest you anyway to check for cluster-frameworks (like http://akka.io) that provide such things (mostly) out of the box.